# OpenCV cvtColor: is information always lost when converting an 8-bit image?

Tags: python, opencv

The documentation for cvtColor states:

> "If you use cvtColor with 8-bit images, the conversion will have some information lost."

Source: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html

Is this true even if you're merely converting from an 8-bit image to an 8-bit image? Or does this simply mean that "deeper" images will be compressed?

Comment: What kind of conversion do you have in mind?

Comment: The documentation appears to be making a general statement, and I'm asking if that statement is true, or if the documentation is simply poorly worded here.

Comment: In general, most conversions involve multiplication by floating point constants and/or division. With only an 8-bit integer to store the result, you will encounter rounding errors and those will accumulate. There are exceptions -- RGB <-> BGR is just a swap of channels, no loss here. Gray -> RGB[A] isn't loosing anything either.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was after!